# How to get the particuler object fields using ReativeMongo without a case class

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

My MongoDB document is

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59f9850e44b0e37ffba68899"),
"code":32,
"sweet" : {
    "reddy" : 0.0,
    "sekhar" : 1.0,
    "praveen" : 1.0,
    "all" : 1.0
},
"salt" : {
    "reddy" : 0.0,
    "sekhar" : 1.0,
    "praveen" : 1.0,
    "all" : 1.0
},
"pepper" : {
    "reddy" : 0.0,
    "sekhar" : 1.0,
    "praveen" : 1.0,
    "all" : 1.0
},
"All" : {
    "reddy" : 0.0,
    "sekhar" : 1.0,
    "praveen" : 1.0,
    "all" : 1.0
}
}
```

How can i get the only one particular Object field values without writing the new case classe for Objects.

I have tried to get them for particular Object following queries in **mongo command prompt**

```
db.test.find({code:{$in:[32]},{new: 0 }}).pretty();

db.test.find({code:{$in:[32]},{new: 1}}).pretty();

db.test.find({code:{$in:[32]},{"new": 1}}).pretty();

db.test.find({code:{$in:[32]},{"new": 0}}).pretty();
```

Comment: Do you mean `db.test.find({ code: 32 },{ "pepper": 1 })`? Not really clear what you are asking. Perhaps, "show your expected result"

Comment: This is my expected output
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59f981dd44b0e37ffba68898"),
        "pepper" : {
         "reddy" : 0,
    "sekhar" : 1,
    "praveen" : 1,
    "all" : 1
        }
}

Comment: db.test.find({ code: 32 },{ "pepper": 1 }) it's working fine Thank you